# How to use NSPredicate to fetch request and populate second viewController with data when UItableView roll is pressed in first viewController

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm coding a Note App in Swift 4. The root ViewController (NoteListViewController) gets populated when secondViewController (ComposeNoteViewController) Textfield and TextView are populated.
The problem is when I press a populated TableView cell, rather than fetch and display the content, it opens a fresh instance of theComposeNoteViewController.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NoteListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var noteListArray = [NoteListItem]()



    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        loadNoteListItem()
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return noteListArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NoteListItemCell", for: indexPath)


        cell.textLabel?.text = noteListArray[indexPath.row].title

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: - TABLEVIEW DELEGATE METHODS
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToComposeNote", sender: self)

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ComposeNoteViewController

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedNoteList = noteListArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
```

---

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class ComposeNoteViewController: UIViewController {

    var noteComposeItemsArray = [ComposeNote]()
    var noteListArray = [NoteListItem]()
    // let noteListController = NoteListTableViewController()
 let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    var selectedNoteList : NoteListItem? {
        didSet {
            loadComposeItem()

        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var noteTextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var noteTextField: UITextField!    

    @IBAction func noteSavePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let newNoteTitleItem = NoteListItem(context: context)
        let newComposeNote = ComposeNote(context: context)
        newNoteTitleItem.title = noteTextField.text!
        newComposeNote.note  = noteTextView.text!
        newComposeNote.parentTitleNote = selectedNoteList

        noteComposeItemsArray.append(newComposeNote)
        noteListArray.append(newNoteTitleItem)
        saveComposeItems()


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }


    func saveComposeItems() {

        do {
            try context.save()
        }catch {
            print("Error saving context \(error)")
        }
    reloadInputViews()
    }

    func loadComposeItem() {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<ComposeNote> = ComposeNote.fetchRequest()
         let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentTitleNote.title MATCHES %@", selectedNoteList!.title!)
            request.predicate = predicate


       do {
           noteComposeItemsArray = try context.fetch(request)
        }catch {
            print("Can't load Items")
        }

         reloadInputViews()

      }
    }
```

Comment: Probably sequencing. You rely on the didSet to trigger the load at the segue but there’s no guarantee that viewDidLoad has fired at that point. add loadComposeItem to viewDidLoad and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: HI Warren, I did as suggested but it crashed. It said the predicate cannot be empty. Thanks